# Chain rule for differentiation with a constant, e.g. $y(x(t)), x = \alpha t$

Tags: chain-rule

I'm solving the following equation:
$$xy'' +y' +k^2xy = 0$$
By setting $x = \alpha t$ and choosing $\alpha$ such that the equation becomes a Bessel equation, shown below with the general solution:
$$xy'' +y' +xy = 0$$
$$y = AJ_o(x)+BY_o(x)$$
So if I plug in $x = \alpha t$:
$$\alpha ty'' +y'+k^2\alpha ty = 0$$
and since $y = y(x(t))$, we have to do chain differentiation and 
$$y'' = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}(\frac{dx}{dt})^2$$
$$y' = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$$
Where $\frac{dx}{dt} = \alpha$, leading to:
$$\alpha^3 ty'' +\alpha y'+k^2\alpha ty = 0$$
But I think this is where I'm messing up and I'm supposed to divide by $\alpha$ to get
$$\frac{1}{\alpha} ty'' +\frac{1}{\alpha} y'+k^2\alpha ty = 0$$
And then I can multiply by $\alpha$ and set $\alpha = \frac{1}{k}$ and it's back in good form:
$$ty'' + y'+ty = 0$$
So how am I messing up the chain rule?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Take care to the symbols: $y'={d y \over d x}$, you want to rewrite the equation using ${d y \over d t}=y'/ {d x \over d t}$

Comment: Edit: good call N74, thanks Edit2: Wait is that the answer? That's the answer! Ahhh okay! Thanks!

Comment: Wait never mind I'm still confused. So I see that we want the entire equation to be in terms of $t$, so $y''(t)$ and so on. But why is $y'(t) = \frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dx}{dt}$? $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy} {dx}\frac{dx} {dt}$

Comment: It seems I messed the symbols again... What I wanted to say is that you have to replace $y'$ with ${dy \over dt} / {dx \over d t}$

Comment: But why? I thought the chain rule was as I showed. Are you saying $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}$? Then $y' = y'(x)$ which doesn't fit with the equation does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are confused, don't use the same symbol $y'$ for two different notations :

$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}\quad$ and $\quad y'=\frac{dy}{dt}\quad$ .

Instead of the ambiguous $\quad xy'' +y' +k^2xy = 0\quad $ a less ambiguous notation is :
$$x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} +\frac{dy}{dx} +k^2xy = 0$$

Also, to avoid confusion, use a different symbol for the functions 
$$y(x)=Y(t)$$
$x = \alpha t \quad\to\quad y(\alpha t)=Y(t) \quad\text{or}\quad y(x)=Y\left(\frac{x}{\alpha} \right) $

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dY}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{dY}{dt}$

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{dY}{dt}\right)\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\frac{d^2Y}{dt^2}$

$$x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} +\frac{dy}{dx} +k^2xy = (\alpha t)\left( \frac{1}{\alpha^2}\frac{d^2Y}{dt^2}\right) +\left( \frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{dY}{dt}\right) +k^2(\alpha t)Y = 0$$

$$  t\frac{d^2Y}{dt^2} + \frac{dY}{dt} +k^2\alpha^2 tY = 0$$
This allows to find a convenient value of $\alpha$ so that $k^2\alpha^2=1$

$$\alpha=\frac{1}{k} \quad\to\quad t\frac{d^2Y}{dt^2} + \frac{dY}{dt}+ tY = 0$$
The general solution of this Bessel ODE is :
$$Y(t)=AJ_0(t)+BY_0(t)$$
Coming back to the variable $\quad x=\alpha t=\frac{1}{k}t \quad\to\quad t=kx \quad \text{and}\quad Y(t)=Y(kx)=y(x)$
$$y(x)=AJ_0(kx)+BY_0(kx)$$
NOTE : Do not confuse

$\quad y(x)=AJ_0(kx)+BY_0(kx)\quad$ which is solution of $\quad x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} +\frac{dy}{dx} +k^2xy = 0$

and

$\quad y(x)=AJ_0(x)+BY_0(x)\quad$ which is solution of $\quad x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} +\frac{dy}{dx} +xy = 0$

Of course, when one becomes very familiar with the notation $y'$ and with the functions $y(x)$ and $y(t)$ and dummy variables, in case of change of variable, he can use the "ambiguous" notations without mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was too cocky and really should've been more careful with my notation. I'll be more careful until I'm more familiar!